# Run yarn script into crontab

Tags: node.js, typescript, cron, ts-node

I made a script in TypeScript that download data from some api and store inside a mongo DB.
If i run `yarn start` from the app folder it works well.
I would like to put this command in a cron job that will be executed every 5 minutes.

I try it with some sintax in crontab but ti doesn't work.
I try to put the call in a run.sh script but it doesn't work too.

```
*/5 * * * * cd /opt/app-folder/src/ && /home/username/.nvm/versions/node/v16.15.1/bin/ts-node main.ts
*/5 * * * * cd /opt/app-folder && /usr/bin/yarn start > /home/username/app-name-out.txt
*/5 * * * * /home/username/run.sh  > /home/username/app-name-out.txt
*/5 * * * * /home/username/.nvm/versions/node/v16.15.1/bin/ts-node /opt/app-folder/src/main.ts > /home/username/app-name-out.txt
*/5 * * * * cd /opt/app-folder/src/ && /home/username/.nvm/versions/node/v16.15.1/bin/ts-node main.ts > /home/username/app-name-out.txt
```

Can someone help me to execute the main.ts every 5 minutes?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I get rid of this problem.
There was 2 problems, the first related to the output redirection.
I fixed by redirect `stdout` in a file and `stderr` in another one.
The second was related the the `$PATH` of crontab: it was `/usr/bin:/bin`.
To fix it I log into my user where script works and I print my $PATH with `echo $PATH`.

I copied the value and I set it before the crontab line in crontab file.
This is what it looks like:

```
# Set the same path of user username to have the correct path in script
PATH=/home/username/.nvm/versions/node/v16.15.1/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/snap/bin
# Execute oracle every 5 minutes
*/5 * * * * /bin/sh /home/username/run.sh >> /home/username/app-name-info.txt 2>> /home/username/app-name-error.txt
```

Now it works.